# Como pegar colunas especificas no Object do JS

Tags: javascript, json

O código a seguir ira me retornar o seguinte resultado:

```js
/**
 * Dados
 */
let data =
    [
        { data: "01/01/2021", value1: "21", value2: "98" },
        { data: "02/01/2021", value3: "22", value4:  "99"},
        { data: "03/01/2021", value5: "36", value6: "100" }
    ];


/**
 * O header são as keys
 * Pegando apenas os values e inserindo numa lista vázia
 */
let values = [];
values.push(Object.keys(data[0]));
function getValues(data) {
    let arr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        arr.push(Object.values(data[i]));
    }
    return arr;
}
values = values.concat(getValues(data));

console.log(values);
```

```
[
  [ 'data', 'value1', 'value2' ],
  [ '01/01/2021', '21', '98' ],
  [ '02/01/2021', '22', '99' ],
  [ '03/01/2021', '36', '100' ]
]
```

Eu preciso transformar em *Inteiro* todos os valores das colunas "value1" e "value2".
Como obter apenas os valores das colunas "value1" e "value2" ?

Comment: Você quer modificar a _tabela_ (convertendo os tipos) ou só retornar um novo array com todos os valores no tipo numérico?

Comment: Vale lembrar que `Object.values` não garante nenhuma ordem de saída específica, então pode haver comportamento inesperado a depender de algumas situações.

Comment: retornar um novo array com todos os valores no tipo numérico. Estou ciente sobre a ordenação.

Comment: @LuizFelipe. `Object.values` garante sim a ordem de saída que é a mesma ordem de a ordem original de inserção. Está documentado [`aqui`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) que *O método Object.values() retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem provida pelo for...in laço* e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) *O laço for...in  interage sobre propriedades enumeradas de um objeto, na ordem original de inserção*

Comment: @AugustoVasques, parece que é algo recente então, porque diversas fontes indicam que a ordem não é garantida (e de fato é o que eu pensava). Ver [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_em_arrays_e_for...in), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/7445826), etc... De modo geral, vendo agora, acho que a partir do ES6, a ordem é, de fato, garantida. Mas ainda estou procurando por referências na spec.

Comment: [Ver constatação no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/EnbV62) cc: @AugustoVasques — Confesso que achei estranho... Mas do JS, não poderíamos esperar menos, né? :P

Comment: @LuizFelipe, É a ordem do `for...in` mas num sentido prático realmente não tem como confiar na ordem de retorno de `Object.values` pois  se houver chaves numéricas ele as coloca a frente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a exceção do cabeçalho da tabela (a primeira "linha"), os valores numéricos posicionam-se nas colunas dois e três (indexadas como 1 e 2, respectivamente).

Desse modo, basta iterar sobre todas as linhas e suas respectivas colunas e converter para número os elementos de colunas cujo índice seja igual a 1 ou 2.

Algo assim:

```js
const table = [
  ['data', 'value1', 'value2'],
  ['01/01/2021', '21', '98'],
  ['02/01/2021', '22', '99'],
  ['03/01/2021', '36', '100']
];

const numbers = [];

// Note que começamos a iteração das linhas pelo índice 1 para ignorar o cabeçalho (a primeira linha):
for (let rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < table.length; rowIndex++) {
  const row = table[rowIndex];

  for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.length; columnIndex++) {
    if (columnIndex === 1 || columnIndex === 2) {
      const num = parseInt(row[columnIndex], 10);
      numbers.push(num);
    }
  }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

E claro, se o número de colunas for muito grande, pode acabar ficando impraticável manter uma condição no `if` para cada índice numérico. Nesse caso, você pode criar um conjunto com os índices numéricos a serem considerados:

```js
const table = [
  ['data', 'value1', 'value2'],
  ['01/01/2021', '21', '98'],
  ['02/01/2021', '22', '99'],
  ['03/01/2021', '36', '100']
];

const numberIndexes = new Set([1, 2]); // Índices das colunas numéricas (somente estas serão considerados)
const numbers = [];

for (let rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < table.length; rowIndex++) {
  const row = table[rowIndex];

  for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.length; columnIndex++) {
    if (numberIndexes.has(columnIndex)) {
      const num = parseInt(row[columnIndex], 10);
      numbers.push(num);
    }
  }
}

console.log(numbers);
```